# Translate 'good time to talk'

Tags: traducción

What is the natural way to translate 'good time to talk', as in a phone conversation that you would like to have with a friend later?

For example, how would you say '5pm is a good time to talk for me' in Spanish? To translate it literally sounds a little awkward: 'Las 5 es un buen momento para hablar por mi'.

Comment: BTW asking for translations without showing your effort or explaining the part you don't understand is off-topic here.

Comment: The OP is proposing a translation of their own: `Las 5 es un buen momento para hablar por mi` and it sounds akward to them, thus, their are asking for other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> '5pm is a good time to talk for me'

Here's what my ear recommends for Mexico -- I don't know about other places.  It would be more polite to pose a question.  Culturally, others will understand that even though you are expressing yourself in a question, you are still making your preference understood.  I have heard people from various parts of the Caribbean and Africa use this approach when talking in English.

This is similar to something we do in English -- notice that "It would be more polite" is softer than "It is more polite."

Thus, a couple of simple versions would be

> ¿Podemos hablar a las 5?
>
> ¿Podríamos vernos a las 5?
>
> ¿Te puedo llamar como a las 5?  *(Can I call you at around 5?)*

If you know the person well:

> ¿Me llamas a las 5?
>
> Te llamo a las 5, ¿está bien?
>
> ¿Vas a estar disponible a las 5?

Here are two verbs that would be a bit more precise:

***quedar***

I'm not finding the right definition in Linguée or DRAE, unfortunately.  You would use this verb to say that a certain shirt fits you well (in terms of size) or that it combines well (in terms of color) with a certain pair of pants or that it suits you (in terms of style).  In scheduling, it would mean that a certain time would be *comfortable* for you.

***convenir***

> suit ([Linguée](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=convenir))

Thus, the following would be a bit more formal (but not to the point of being stuffy) than the earlier proposals:

> ¿Lo puedo llamar más tarde?  ¿Le quedaría bien a las 5 de la tarde?
>
> ¿Podríamos platicar [conversar] más tarde?  Le conviene [convendría] llamarme como a las cinco?  *(Could we talk later?  Would around 5:00 be convenient?)*

You can also express regret and say when you'll free up:

> Disculpa, ando un poco apurado/a ahorita pero voy a estar disponible a partir de las 5. *(I'm sorry, I'm in a bit of a hurry just now but I'll be available any time from 5 on.)*

Comment: Thanks for this really in-depth comment! I am currently in Mexico, so I appreciate the explanation on the cultural context as well. I have noticed during my time here that asking a question implies your preference, which is not always the case in English. Would you say that it would be seen as rude to express my preference upfront, at least for a friend/friendly acquaintance?

Comment: @Nate - It might come across as a bit in-your-face, or perhaps a bit up tight.  However, if you are a fairly recent arrival, people will likely take that into account and forgive what might otherwise be a social faux pas.

Answer (score 4):

The "direct" translation is actually the form used in Spanish

> Las 5 es un buen momento para hablar para mi

You could also use other forms, like

> Me viene mejor hablar a las 5
>
> Prefería hablar a las 5
>
> Te viene bien hablar ahora (when calling someone on the phone)

Comment: This answer is correct but it sounds too "Spaniard". @Nate if you are interested in Spanish from Spain accept this as an answer or add a regional tag to your question to get more localized answers.

Answer (score 1):

In Chile, in an informal situation, we prefer to say

> Para mí las 5 es *buena hora para hablar*.

However (as Diego thinks) that is a direct translation that we would not use. Instead we would probably say

> *Me acomoda* que hablemos a las 5.
>
> A las 5 *está bien* que hablemos.

And in more formal situations:

> Para mí, las 5 es una *hora adecuada* para que hablemos.